# How to fix this pip3 bug?

Tags: ubuntu, pip

Each time I use pip3 I receive an exception, e.g. `pip3 install regex`, an error occurs: `AttributeError: '_NamespacePath' object has no attribute 'sort'`

Meanwhile, if I type a command with error, e.g. `$ git clone https://github.com/NVIDIA/apex` (the extra `$` is intentional), it also occurs: `AttributeError: '_NamespacePath' object has no attribute 'sort'`.

I reset the account and things are fine now.

Comment: Try uninstalling and re-installing pip3 and updating setuptools. https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/2990 `pip3 install --upgrade pip3 setuptools`

Comment: @swagrov I tried this but since this command contains "pip3", it will result in this error "AttributeError: '_NamespacePath' object has no attribute 'sort'
"

Comment: How did you initially install pip3? Can you uninstall it without using pip? If this is ubuntu, you might be able to do it with `apt remove python3-pip`

Comment: @swagrov, I tried this before, but things do not change. Anyway, I reset my account and things are fine now. Thanks